# Vue template object key alternative reference without implicitly calling with key name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object which is retrieved from an API and key names are unknown. Let's assume it will come in the following format:

```
var attributes = {
  "Colour": ["red", "black", "purple"],
  "Size": ["8.0", "8.5", "9.0", "9.5", "10.0"]}
```

How can I access this data directly in Vue without knowing keys? I know the following would work if I had known the keys, but I am looking for an option where I can refer to the arrays without knowing the key names, like normal Javascript values are accessed through key name (square brackets).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(values, name) in attributes"> [[ name ]]</th>
    </tr>
    <td>
        <select">
            <option v-for="value in attributes.Colour"> [[ value ]] </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select">
            <option v-for="value in attributes.Size"> [[ value ]] </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</table>
```

[image]

I have tried this so far (e.g. `attributes[name]`), which does not seem to be correct Vue template syntax:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(values, name) in attributes"> [[ name ]]</th>
    </tr>
    <td v-for="value in attributes[name]">
        <select">
            <option> [[ value ]] </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this.
Since your `attributes` is an object with dynamic keys, loop through the object to get the keys.
Then loop through each of the keys of the object `attributes` to get array list.
Also, the `<td>` tag should be wrapped inside a `<tr>` tag

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {
         attributes : {
         "Colour": ["red", "black", "purple"],
         "Size": ["8.0", "8.5", "9.0", "9.5", "10.0"]}
         },
         methods: {
          
         }
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(item, key, index) in attributes "> {{ key }}     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td v-for="(item, key, index) in attributes">
        <select>
            <option v-for="name in item"> {{ name }} </option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexes. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for.

```html
<table>
    <td>
        <select v-for="(value, index) in attributes">
            <option> {{ attributes[index] }} </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</table>
```

I'm also somehow lost in your code, because I'm not sure if you want to render more `options`, `selects`or `tds`. In my example there will be rendered a number of options based on the attributes that you pass into select's `v-for`.

Comment: I do not think we are understanding each other, each element has an array which needs to be looped through as well, in any case see the screegrab of expected output.